# 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, ubuntu-10.10

Context:  I am using a software package called Social Engine. It is extremely buggy.

Anyway, I asked (paid even) the Social Engine people to do an upgrade and when they finally did so, I logged into the site and noticed that the styles were all missing. I opened a support ticket and all they told me was that it was a 416 error and to contact my ISP.

This error was found by testing the direct link to the CSS files which are located in a writable folder in the software.

http://ministersdev3.themonastery.org/application/css.php?request=application/themes/monastery-theme/theme.css&c=6

I started doing my research only to find it's an extremely rare error and I couldn't see any suggestions for turning range requesting off on my Ubuntu 10.10 Linode server (running latest Apache and PHP5 with APC extension installed).  Perhaps it's a software issue?  Someway the caching with APC is working?  I reset the caching in this software to 60 seconds and made sure it was using APC.  Still no dice.

Is it something their software may be doing that I would need to look into patching?

Comment: just as a heads up, i got the message after updating a video on the server - the name was the same but the content was different. I changed the version by adding `?v1` at the end of the filename and solved it, another options would have been to clear to browser cache.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue could be due to your browser having cached the original CSS files and trying to request byte ranges of the new files. See for example [this bug with Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68298).

As far as disabling range requesting, it might not be necessary if you clear your browser cache, but if you need it you could try the following Apache config:

```
Header unset Accept-Ranges
```

This will tell clients that they cannot use the `Range` request header to request byte ranges of your files.

Answer (score 7):

I have, at the top of my .htaccess file

```
Header set Accept-Ranges none
RequestHeader unset Range
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Intercept the headers coming back from your ISP and verify that you're getting a 416 status code.  If so, intercept the headers you are sending to your ISP and drop the range header; this should force the server to send you the entire file.